# How to define endian enum class waiting for C++20?

Tags: c++, endianness

Considering the possible implementation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian):

```
enum class endian
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    little = 0,
    big    = 1,
    native = little
#else
    little = __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__,
    big    = __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__,
    native = __BYTE_ORDER__
#endif
};
```

Is it sure that

```
__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__, __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__, __BYTE_ORDER__
```

are defined in other platforms than WIN32?

Before C++20 is released, is it possible to define such an enum for endianness?
Otherwise, how to do it properly?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [boost endian](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/endian/doc/conversion.html)

Comment: Is it possible? Sure, but I'm seeing a similar enum in [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/endian/doc/conversion.html) so maybe that would do?

Comment: The "possible implementation" is not a standardized or otherwise official way of implementing the enumeration. Instead it depends a *lot* on the compiler used and its corresponding standard library parts. What is shown is only a *possibility*, an *example* without any basis on real implementations.

Comment: for gcc see here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html

Comment: This is going to compiler dependent.  If you need something poratable use [Boost.Endian](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/endian/doc/index.html)

Comment: @user463035818 but I am wondering if those macro are garanteed to be defined.

Comment: They are not.  `std::endian` is the guaranteed interface.  However your implementation implements it is up to them.

Comment: That's my question thank you

Comment: the macros used in the example are those defined for gcc. For other compilers you have to check their documentation